# Change colors in a CAGradientLayer after inserting

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I have a class function to create a CAGradient layer and insert it to a UIView which works fine.

However, I'd like to modify the gradient after the page is shown, and re-executing the same function does not work.

On the displayed page I use sliders to set new colors into two UIButton backgrounds, and call the function below. I'm expecting the gradient layer background to change when I change the slider but it doesn't. I've verified that the function is being called and the color values are valid.

How can I change the gradient as I move the sliders?

Here's the class function:

```
class func setGradientBG(_ firstColor: CGColor, secondColor: CGColor, vertical: Bool, thisView: UIView){
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = thisView.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [firstColor, secondColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.2]
    if !vertical{
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    }
    thisView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

And here's the function called from the sliders:

```
func doSlider(){
   CommonFuncs.setGradientBG((self.TopColorBut.backgroundColor?.cgColor)!,  secondColor: (self.BottomColorBut.backgroundColor?.cgColor)!, vertical: true, thisView: self.view)
}
```

Comment: use thisView.layer.setNeedsDisplay()

Comment: What class contains that `doSlider` method? How many different views are you adding gradients to? Why is `setGradientBG` a class method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding another instance of `CAGradientLayer` every time you call `setGradientBG`. Do you really think that's a good idea?

It looks like your `doSlider` method is probably part of a custom `UIViewController` subclass. What you should do is store a reference to the gradient layer in the view controller, and update that existing layer. Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    @IBOutlet var topColorButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var bottomColorButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
        self.updateGradientLayer()
    }

    @IBAction func doSlider() {
        updateGradientLayer()
    }

    private func updateGradientLayer() {
        gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.2 ]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = .zero
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradientLayer.colors = [
            (topColorButton.backgroundColor ?? .clear).cgColor,
            (bottomColorButton.backgroundColor ?? .clear).cgColor ]
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
    }

}
```

Comment: I was wondering about that - adding multiple layers. I'll make some changes to my code so that the layer is added in the view controller and just modified via the common function.

Answer (score 0):

Sublayers are listed in back to front order. So insert the new sublayer at last. Or remove old ones.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I think Rob has the answer below. I need to re-write my function so that I can keep a reference to the added layer.